# Как создать статический маршрут через прокси windows 11

Tags: маршрутизация, route, прокси

Как можно создать статический маршрут через прокси.Есть 2 подключения к пк(ethernet и wi-fi)Как можно перенаправлять 1 сайт с ip 123.456.7.8, через прокси на ethernet, а остальные соединения через wi-fi?
Есть команда route add но не понятно как направлять запрос через прокси.Так же нашел Tun2Socks он как раз кидает запрос через прокси но не понял как перенаправить на определенный адаптер сети.ОС win 11
Пробова:

```
route add ipпрокси mask 255.255.0.0 IPv4-адрес -p
```

но это так не работает даже при условии то что прокси сейчас включен на все программы.Или можно это сделать через роутер keenetic или какое устройство надо для этого если не сильно дорого стоит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смог решить проблему для этого я подключил 2 сети к роутеру и там прокинул уже маршрут.[Ссылка на инструкцию](https://help.keenetic.com/hc/ru/articles/360000925780-%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B)